# MYSQL date validation head-scratcher

Tags: mysql, date, mysql-5.7

I'm running into an issue trying to insert dates into a table that I can't figure out for the life of me.  Let's say I do this:

```
select "2018-11-40" from dual where dayname("2018-02-31") is not null;
```

I correctly get 0 rows back, since Nov 40th isn't a valid day.

But if I have a table MY_TABLE with a date field `EVENT_DATE`, and do this:

```
insert into MY_TABLE (EVENT_DATE)

select "2018-11-40" from dual where dayname("2018-11-40") is not null;
```

It errors out with: Incorrect datetime value: '2018-11-40', rather than running with no errors and 0 rows affected.

`(dayname("2018-11-40") is not null)` definitely should resolve as false before the insert... and if I do this:

```
insert into MY_TABLE (EVENT_DATE)
select "2018-11-40" from dual where 1=2;
```

everything works fine (no errors.  0 rows affected).

So what gives?  This is on MySQL 5.7.21

Comment: Calling `DAYNAME()` on an invalid date causes the error, so if you avoid doing that, no error?

Comment: The first example uses Feb 31 as the date, not Nov 40.

Comment: What is the problem that you think exists here?

Comment: sorry, typo on the Feb 31, but that doesn't make a difference.  select "2018-11-40" from dual where dayname("2018-11-40") is not null;  - returns 0 rows, so the insert shouldn't trigger an error, it should just insert 0 rows.

Comment: calling DAYNAME() on an invalid date doesn't cause an error, it returns null, which is what i'm testing for.  Using STR_TO_DATE() for the same purpose (to check if a date is valid before inserting that row) has the same issue.  For some reason the conditional doesn't get respected with doing an insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With mysql 5.7, your initial query of `select "2018-11-40" from dual where dayname("2018-02-31") is not null;` actually is generating a warning.

You can see this warning by following that query directly with `show warnings;`

You should see something similar to this:

```
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '2018-02-31' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I understand you correctly, what you found problematic was what you perceived as the variation in behavior from a test select to the case where you tried to use the select as input to an insert.

The answer to this question is related to the [various server sql mode settings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) you can configure.

What you are seeing is a combination of a "strict mode" in conjunction with the default setting of NO_ZERO_DATE.  The manual says this about that combination of settings:

> If this mode and strict mode are enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.

Your invalid dates are being converted to '00' and this triggers a warning when you are noodling around with SELECT, but a full blown error if you then try to combine that with an INSERT.

Comment: yep, just modifying my query to use INSERT IGNORE did the trick.  thanks for the explanations on why this was error-ing out to begin with.

Comment: nicely explained. +10

Answer (score 1):

In a DML statement (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE), the `1292` is an error.

But in a `SELECT` statement, the `1292` is not an error. It's a warning, so the statement can continue processing.

```
Query: select '2018-11-40' + INTERVAL 0 DAY

1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s)

Warning Code : 1292
Incorrect datetime value: '2018-11-40'
```

---

The SELECT statement is throwing a warning. MySQL reports it, but your client app is ignoring it.

The difference is that with a *warning* condition, the statement can continue processing. In the context of an `INSERT` statement, the 1292 is an error, and the statement processing halts.

(There might be settings of `sql_mode` that influence this behavior in MySQL 5.7,   for example, to get the SELECT statement to throw an error instead of a warning.)

---

We can see the same behavior with error 1411.  It's an error in DML, a warning in a SELECT.

```
Query: select STR_TO_DATE('2018-11-40','%Y-%m-%d')

1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s)

Warning Code : 1411
Incorrect datetime value: '2018-11-40' for function str_to_date
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess that makes sense then.  Is there any simple, one sql statement way of doing a batch insert of rows with dates derived from a string where some dates may be invalid and should be skipped?  i can script this out, but just curious if i'm missing some cool trick.